# How to write mysql stored procedure using like operator

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Following is my code:

```
     DELIMITER $$

     CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `employee_with_asset`(IN name     VARCHAR(250))
     BEGIN
     SELECT a.Asset_code,a.name as name1,a.type,a.description,`purchase date`,
    `amc availability`,`amc renewal`,`employee Id`,b.Name FROM `asset_details` a,
     employee b WHERE  b.Name LIKE '%' + @name + '%' and a.`assigned to`=b.`employee Id`;
     END
```

It is showing error near LIKE. How to solve it.

Comment: You have to use `CONCAT()` instead of "+"

Answer (score 42, accepted):

the concatenation in mysql is done using `CONCAT()`

```
LIKE CONCAT('%', @name , '%')
```

FULL STATEMENT

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `employee_with_asset`
(
    IN _name     VARCHAR(250)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT  a.Asset_code,
            a.name as name1,
            a.type,
            a.description,
            `purchase date`,
            `amc availability`,
            `amc renewal`,
            `employee Id`,
            b.Name 
    FROM    `asset_details` a
            INNER JOIN employee b 
                ON a.`assigned to` = b.`employee Id`
    WHERE   b.Name LIKE CONCAT('%', _name , '%');
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: +1 It's like the answer I wrote (and delete to don't duplicate). So I think it'll do the trick. You're quick...

Comment: what errors do you get? it's not working can have multiple meaning

Comment: @JW: Thanks a lot. Now it is working. Earlier it was returning empty row. Now i got the result.

Comment: you're welcome `:D` the problem was with the parameter `name` and you use `@name` in the like clause. But I change it to `_name` to avoid name collision.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of John Woo is right but if you don't use utf8_general_ci collection, you must cast collection after WHERE clause (after each condition if you have multiple conditions) as the same as collection of the column you compare to like this

```
... WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', @name , '%') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

or multiple conditions

```
... WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', @name , '%') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
OR job LIKE CONCAT('%', @name , '%') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ...
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP:

```
$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
$response = "call user_search('%$keyword%');";
```

Mysql:

```
....where user.name like @keyword;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found in this post [Re: Passing a parameter to a LIKE operator](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,145092,157269#msg-157269). I need to make a sql sentence like a string then execute the sentence.

```
-- DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS db1.SelectEmpleados;

CREATE PROCEDURE SelectEmpleados(IN var varchar(100) )
BEGIN
    
    SET @qry = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE CONCAT(nombre, \' \',apellido) LIKE \'%', var, '%\'');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END

-- CALL SelectEmpleados();
```

For me doesn't work on MariaDB 10.4.27:

```
WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', @name , '%')
WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', name , '%')
WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', "@name" , '%')
WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', @"name" , '%')
WHERE name LIKE '%'+name+'%'
```